# Calculus I Find Integral of sin(x) value

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, substitution

I'm a bit stuck on this problem.

[image]

I'm assuming using the substitution $u = 2 + 6x^3.$  And I can find du from there.  But I'm stuck on how to take the integral of sin(u).

I would really appreciate it if someone can walk me through this problem step by step.

Here is where I'm stuck:

[image]

In my problem what value is a?

Comment: an antiderivative of $\sin u$ is $-$cos $u$

Comment: The derivative of $-cos(u)$ is $sin(u)$ and so the integral of $sin(u)$ is $-cos(u)$. That is an elementary integral.

Comment: i dont' think it's that simple.  integral of sin ax dx = -1/a (cos ax) + C ... that's the part I want to see stepped out in this problem

Comment: You substituted $u$ for everything inside the parentheses, so $a=1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int 90x^2\sin(2+6x^3)dx=\int5\sin u du=-5\cos u+C=-5\cos(2+6x^3)+C$$

Comment: question for you ... shouldn't -5 be multiplied against 1/a ?  based on formula I added into my original post.

Comment: when applying that formula to $\int \sin u du$, $a$ is $1$

Comment: because $\sin u=\sin 1u$

Comment: gotcha, I didn't realize the impact of the u substitution ... thank you